Хранение строк подключения к базе данных PostgreSQL в C#
Есть консольное приложение на C#, версия 8, так же на localhost работает PostreSQL. Создал файл App.config, записал в него следующее
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyDB"
        providerName="Npgsql"
        connectionString="Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=mypassword;Database=postgres"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Добавил директиву using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
Пытаюсь с помощью ConfigurationManager получить строку, но не вижу массива ConnectionStrings (Что-то вроде такого должно получиться ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString) Там лежат только поля, наследованные от object

Так Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration и не работает с App.config. Вы ведь сами в коде написали то, что у вас должно быть, это и реализуйте. Пишем в гугл ConfigurationManager, первой ссылкой находим документацию, видим там пакет System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, устанавливаем, пользуемся. Я бы вам альтернативу, более лучшую посоветовал, связанную именно с Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, но на сколько я помню, вы против альтернатив, так что... Удачи в решении.

Мужик я не против альтернатив, может я тогда вспылил не спорю, но как ты вспомнил)

Я с вами на ТЫ не переходил... "Как ты вспомнил" - трудно забыть, когда идет критика всего сообщества, а потом и вовсе "побег" из этого сообщество на англ. SO с надеждой, что там ответят "как надо". Ну да ладно... Хотите альтернативу - советую получше изучить Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, как он устанавливается, как им пользоваться, изучите его IOption и т.д. App.config - это всеж устаревший формат настроек, современные проекты сейчас не использую его, ибо есть именно Configuration и appsettings.json. Да и JSON куда более удобный, чем XML. Но это так, совет...
